# Generating a square Numpy array of a given size, using column and row values in calculations

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array of one-dimensional values of Yk, where each subsequent value of U = random number [0,1], k =1,2,3..N . I need to build an array of size NxN, which will be filled with a different condition, which depends on the index of the row and column.
If the index of the column and row for the array cell are equal (i=m) 2π+0.1*U_k, i=m, then the array cell is filled by the upper condition sin(i-k) * cos⁡π(i-k), i≠m, and otherwise by the lower one.
I did not deal with the fact that the rows and columns of the array participated in the filling of this array, so I got confused with the implementation. I only need a working basis for padding, so a finite array of NxN is enough for 4x4.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITLzh.jpg)

simplifying the task, I got a semblance of what I need to get. However, some of the problems remained.

1: instead of the variable U, there should be an element of an array of random numbers within [0,1], this element is U_k, where k is its index in a one-dimensional array. For example, in the array U_k = [0.11, 0.5, 0.66]: U1=0.11, U2=0.5, U3=0.66.

2: Also, instead of the constant output of the variable A, I need to form a one-dimensional array.
In other words, I still have problems with outputting the value from the previously set array U_k and packing the results of the loop execution into a one-dimensional array.

```
import numpy as np
import math 
i=0
k=1
N=5
U=10 
while k < N:

    while i < N:
        i= i+1
        k = k
        if i==k:
            A = 2* math.pi + 0.1 * U
        if i != k:
            A = math.sin(i-k)* math.cos(math.pi*(i-k))
        print(A)
    else:
        i= 1
        k= k+1
```

Comment: Welcome, what you have tried so far? can you show us your code?

Comment: What is definition of U_k? An example of the array can be useful

Comment: @EitanRosati "can you show us your code?"... yes, after some more tinkering, I solved some of the problems and was able to set up the algorithm relatively competently. I still have unresolved issues number 1 and 2 described below. I have laid out the algorithm code to simplify the understanding of the remaining problems.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your U_ks but the question you asked in the title has the following easy solution:

```
np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: i + 10*j, (4, 4))
```

yields

```
array([[ 0, 10, 20, 30],
       [ 1, 11, 21, 31],
       [ 2, 12, 22, 32],
       [ 3, 13, 23, 33]])
```

And obviously you can replace my return line with your U_k/Sine things.

Notice that you can achieve something similar with pure python like so

```
[[i + 10*j for j in range(n)] for i in range(n)]
```

but numpy is ruffly 50 times faster.